# Broken Nexus 6p Recovery

Tags: data-recovery, touchscreen, broken-screen, nexus-6p

So while I was overseas in Vietnam I dropped my Nexus 6P and broken the screen.
The screen is completely black and completely unresponsive however when I use the fingerprint scanner it still vibrates.
Stupid me decided to restart the phone by holding down the off button, which I immediately regretted as of course, Now I must enter my PIN to be able to get into my phone.
SO basically, Im asking if its possible to recover any data from my Nexus 6P with a completely unresponsive screen, and requiring PIN on startup.
I Believe that debugging was enabled

Comment: Plug in an OTG adapter then a USB mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Connect your phone to a PC and use ADB to backup your data. Follow this guide to setup ADB, Fastboot and the Android SDK Platform tools on your PC: https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928

Load your phone into `fastboot` mode by holding the `power` button and the `volume down` button at the same time, from there you can choose `recovery` mode by the volume and power buttons navigation of your phone, then access and copy your data from your PC by ADB.

Alternatively you could temporarily load a custom recovery as suggested here:  [can fastboot be used to backup device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137895/can-fastboot-be-used-to-backup-device)

For more Info see this answer here: [Enabling ADB on Nexus 6 with dead screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175747/enabling-adb-on-nexus-6-with-dead-screen?rq=1)