# USB debugging from fastboot

Tags: usb, factory-reset, fastboot, reboot

my son's Moto G7 Power froze, rebooted, and won't get past the blue android screen. I'm preparing to do a reset but want to back up beforehand. RSA won't connect as we haven't previously enabled USB debugging on the phone. Any ideas how I can do this, since I can't get to the menu to enable?

Thanks in advance.

Hamptonoid

Comment: Fastboot doesn't have the ability to perform backups, you need ADB access for that, and even then it's not that great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can fastboot be used to backup device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137895/can-fastboot-be-used-to-backup-device)

Comment: fastboot is disabled so one can't boot/flash TWRP. there is no way to backup data. phone cannot boot, one can't pass the lock screen, therefore data cannot decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. In the end I forced the factory reset through RSA and fortunately Google had backed up the profile, so once I'd connected to the correct account it restored it all. I didn't even realise that this was a thing (I'd assumed I'd just get photos restored).
Cheers